# Using Python, how to return just one value instead of an entire row in an SQL query

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a SQL database file which contains a multitude of columns, two of which are 'GEO_ID' and 'MED_INCOME'. I am trying to retrieve just the 'MED_INCOME' column data using the associated 'GEO_ID'. Here is what I thought would work:

```
import sqlite3 as db

def getIncome(censusID):
    conn = db.connect('census.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT 'MED_INCOME' FROM censusDbTable WHERE GEO_ID = %s" % (censusID)
    response = c.fetchall()
    c.close()
    conn.close()
    return response

id = 60014001001
incomeValue = getIncome(id)
print("incomeValue: ", incomeValue)
```

Which results in:

```
incomeValue: [('MED_INCOME',)]
```

I thought that I had used this method before when attempting to retrieve the data from just one column, but this method does not appear to work. If I were to instead write:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM censusDbTable WHERE GEO_ID = %s" % (censusID)
```

I get the full row's data, so I know the ID is in the database file.

Is there something about my syntax that is causing this request to result in an empty set?

Comment: Yes, there is something about your SQL syntax causing this. This question really does not show any research effort.

Comment: Remove the ' ' pair around MED_INCOME. Currently you're treating it as a string when it's meant to be interpreted as a field of a table.

Comment: @Fynn Becker Doesn't show research effort? Are you keeping track of how many searches I did to try to find more info and clarity on this? If you don't know how to answer the question, don't respond.

Comment: @Ernxst Thanks! That was it. I had a feeling it was something seemingly trivial. I appreciate it.

Comment: @NLee23 your question asks if there is something wrong with the syntax, yet you didn't manage to look the correct syntax up on your own. That is indeed poor research if any.

Comment: @FynnBecker you are being needlessly insulting here. OP had almost-working syntax, he just didn't know about the issue with the quotes.

Comment: I'm sorry if this has come across as insulting, that was not my intention.

Comment: No problem @FynnBecker I'm still relatively new to Python and SQL and trying to learn, but there's no way you could have known that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Ernxst comment, I adjusted the request to:

```
c.execute("SELECT MED_INCOME FROM censusDbTable WHERE GEO_ID = %s" % (censusID)
```

Removing the quotes around the column ID, which solved the problem.

Comment: Even better parameterize your query and avoid the very old modulus, `%`, string formatting. This is cleaner and safer: `c.execute("SELECT MED_INCOME FROM censusDbTable WHERE GEO_ID = ?" , (censusID,))`